# ubuntu 16.04 startup blackscreen problem

Tags: startup

I have an AMD a4 processor with pavilion g4 laptop. When I start the laptop, I get a black screen. What should I do?

Comment: laptop is pavilion g4 hp

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `nomodeset` parameter. You can also try `acpi = off` and `nolapic` if `nomodset` also shows up as a black screen.
Have a read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it), this should definitely fix your problem.